# pytest fixture is not getting called in class

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fixtures

I recently started working on a python project. In that project, I am writing test cases using [pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/). In that, I tried using [pytest-fixtures](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html) and understood the basic concepts of it.

But I found difficulty using `fixture` in a particular case, when I was trying to use these fixtures in a `class`.

Sample Code:

```
import pytest

from flask.ext.testing import TestCase

from flask_application import app

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def some_fix():
    return "yes"

class TestDirectoryInit(TestCase):
    def create_app(self):
        return app

    def test_one(self, some_fix):
        assert some_fix == "yes"
```

when I am running this test, it is throwing me an error:

> TypeError: test_one() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

But when I changed this code a little bit like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def some_fix():
    return "yes"

class TestDirectoryInit():

    def test_one(self, some_fix):
        assert some_fix == "yes"
```

Now this test case is getting passed. I am not able to understand that why it is behaving differently due to extending a TestCase class.

Any useful suggestion will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`flask.ext.testing.TestCase` is a subclass of `unittest.TestCase`.

If you want to be able to use pytest fixtures with unittest, please read this:

[Mixing pytest fixtures into unittest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html)

Comment: In `TestDirectoryInit` class, I am writing test case for api calls. For that, I am using `unittest.TestCase`. Can you suggest me some other good method to do that, without using `unittest.TestCase`?

Comment: You could just use pytest alone, it's unittest replacement

Comment: could you write a small example code for that? 
By import Unittest.Testcase, I was able to make a request like : self.client.post(). How we do this using pytest?

Comment: sorry, I'm not a flask user and do not know how to write tests for it, BUT, look what I've found: http://pytest-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html